# how to set concurrency (or other configurations) for ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory per StreamListener

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have scenario where our application(spring boot, spring-cloud-stream based) listens to multiple Kafka topics (TOPIC_A with 3 partitions, TOPIC_B with 1 partition,TOPIC_C with 10 partitions) i.e. 3 @StreamListener methods.

```
   @StreamListener(TopicASink.INPUT)
    public void processTopicA(Message<String> msg) {
        logger.info("** recieved message: {} ", msg.getPayload());
      // do some processing
    }

   @StreamListener(TopicBSink.INPUT)
    public void processTopicB(Message<String> msg) {
        logger.info("** recieved message: {} ", msg.getPayload());
       // do some processing
    }

   @StreamListener(TopicCSink.INPUT)
    public void processTopicC(Message<String> msg) {
        logger.info("** recieved message: {} ", msg.getPayload());
      // do some processing
    }
```

We need customize error handling and retry mechanism hence achieving this by configuring ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean.

```
       @Bean
        public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<Object,Object> consumerFactory) {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConcurrency(2);   // we need to customize this per topic based on number of partitions
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(10));
            factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
            factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(FixedBackOff.DEFAULT_INTERVAL, 10)));
            return factory;
        }
```

Problem is now we need some properties of the KafkaListenerContainer's to vary per @StreamListener (i.e. per topic in this case) , say to have a concurrency of 3 for TOPIC_A, 10 for TOPIC_C etc. instead of common concurrency set on the factory or set SeekToCurrentErrorHandler for TOPIC_A,TOPIC_C but not for TOPIC_B (or different ErrorHandler for some topics).

How can this be achieved per container level?

---

stack trace after trying solution with solution with reflection shared below

```
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception thrown while invoking com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.KafkaStreamPocApplication$MessageProcessor#processInput[1 args]; nested exception is com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.MyNewRetryableException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[35], headers={kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedTopic=new_input_topic, spanTraceId=e3382bf49eaa5343, spanId=e3382bf49eaa5343, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[e3382bf49eaa5343], spanId=[efc90644fc4c7dee], spanSampled=[0], X-B3-TraceId=[e3382bf49eaa5343], X-B3-SpanId=[efc90644fc4c7dee], X-B3-ParentSpanId=[e3382bf49eaa5343], spanParentSpanId=[e3382bf49eaa5343], X-B3-Sampled=[0]}, kafka_offset=26, X-B3-SpanId=e3382bf49eaa5343, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@2a011bf8, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=e3382bf49eaa5343, id=3c86f652-f16e-2f59-1a59-f3d8601849f0, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1, spanSampled=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1586250896206, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for ConsumerRecord(topic = new_input_topic, partition = 1, offset = 26, CreateTime = 1586250896206, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 35, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@68df9f80), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1586274368357}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:387)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:364)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.MyNewRetryableException
    at com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.KafkaStreamPocApplication$MessageProcessor.consumeMessage(KafkaStreamPocApplication.java:164)
    at com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.KafkaStreamPocApplication$MessageProcessor.lambda$processInput$0(KafkaStreamPocApplication.java:107)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
    at com.jta.poc.kafkapoc.KafkaStreamPocApplication$MessageProcessor.processInput(KafkaStreamPocApplication.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container factory is not used in this context.

Add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` `@Bean`.

```
@Bean
public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> cust() {
    return (container, destination, group) -> { ... };
}
```

As you can see, you get a reference to the container, the destination name and the group so you can figure out which binding it is being called for.

```java
/**
 * If a single bean of this type is in the application context, listener containers
 * created by the binder can be further customized after all the properties are set. For
 * example, to configure less-common properties.
 *
 * @param <T> container type
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @author Oleg Zhurakousky
 * @since 2.1
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ListenerContainerCustomizer<T> {

    /**
     * Configure the container that is being created for the supplied queue name and
     * consumer group.
     * @param container the container.
     * @param destinationName the destination name.
     * @param group the consumer group.
     */
    void configure(T container, String destinationName, String group);

}
```

Set the error handler etc., on the container.

**EDIT**

Here is a hack for 2.0.x, if you don't mind using reflection; but bear in mind there was no support for a `BackOff` in the STCEH back then.

Also Boot 2.0 is end of life and hasn't been supported since April last year; so you really should upgrade.

```java
    @Bean
    public SmartLifecycle bindingFixer(BindingService bindingService) {
        return new SmartLifecycle() {

            @Override
            public int getPhase() {
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            @Override
            public void stop() {
                // no op
            }

            @Override
            public void start() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Binding> consumers = (Map<String, Binding>) new DirectFieldAccessor(bindingService)
                        .getPropertyValue("consumerBindings");
                SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler();
                ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) new DirectFieldAccessor(consumers.get("input"))
                        .getPropertyValue("lifecycle.messageListenerContainer")).getContainerProperties()
                            .setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isRunning() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void stop(Runnable callback) {
                callback.run();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAutoStartup() {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but this interface is available with new stream api,  we have another old project using 2.0.0.RELEASE of spring-cloud-stream . Is there a way to achieve similar behavior somehow (any other extension points we can look for)?

Comment: No; `@since 2.1` only; sorry. I'll see if I can find a hack, but it would be better to upgrade.

Comment: I added a hack, but you really should upgrade.

Comment: thanks for the hack, meanwhile we are evaluating if upgrading to newer boot and cloud stream version does not introduce any breaking change for us in existing infrastructure .

Comment: tried with the reflection solution but somehow with it errorhandler is not getting invoked after default container retries are exhaused . i have added a stack trace of error logged when default 3 retries are exausted. the error handler seems to be never. I tried adding a custom error handler with log messages just to see if it gets called but that does not seem to be invoked.

Comment: Double check your work; you must have done something wrong.

Comment: thanks Gary, I re-verified but  still the same, though i see the ContainerProperties are set with errorhandler using reflection mechanism but by that time errorHandler class variable of KafkaMessageListenerContainer is already set to  LoggingErrorHandler hence the custom error handler that we set in ContainerProperties later is not being used.  Am i missing something ?

Comment: Oh; right; in newer versions it was moved from the properties to the container itself. You need to `stop()` and `start()` the container for the  property change to take effect.