# when using @StreamListener, customization to KafkaListenerContainerFactory are getting reflected in generated KafkaMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using spring-cloud-stream with kafka binder to consume message from kafka . The application is basically consuming messages from kafka and updating a database.

There are scenarios when DB is down (which might last for hours) or some other temporary technical issues. Since in these scenarios there is no point in retrying a message for a limited amount of time and then move it to DLQ , i am trying to achieve infinite number of retries when we are getting certain type of exceptions (e.g. DBHostNotAvaialableException)

In order to achieve this i tried 2 approaches (facing issues in both the approaches) -

1. In this approach, Tried setting an errorhandler on container properties while configuring  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean but the error handler is not getting triggered at all.  While debugging the flow i realized in the KafkaMessageListenerContainer that are created have the errorHandler field is null hence they use the default LoggingErrorHandler. Below are my container factory bean configurations - 
   the @StreamListener method for this approach is the same as 2nd approach except for the seek on consumer.

   ```
   @Bean
   public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> 
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
       ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
       factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
       factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
       ContainerProperties containerProperties = factory.getContainerProperties();
        // even tried a custom implementation of RemainingRecordsErrorHandler but call never went in to the implementation
       factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
       return factory;
   }
   ```

Am i missing something while configuring factory bean or this bean is only relevant for @KafkaListener and not @StreamListener??

2. The second alternative was trying to achieve it using manual acknowledgement and seek, Inside a @StreamListener method getting Acknowledgment and Consumer from headers, in case a retryable exception is received, I do certain number of retries using retrytemplate and when those are exhausted I trigger a `consumer.seek()` . Example code below -

   ```
   @StreamListener(MySink.INPUT)
   public void processInput(Message<String> msg) {

   MessageHeaders msgHeaders = msg.getHeaders();
   Acknowledgment ack = msgHeaders.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
   Consumer<?,?> consumer = msgHeaders.get(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER, Consumer.class);
   Integer partition = msgHeaders.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, Integer.class);
   String topicName = msgHeaders.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, String.class);
   Long offset = msgHeaders.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, Long.class);


   try {
     retryTemplate.execute(
               context -> {
                // this is a sample service call to update database which might throw retryable exceptions like DBHostNotAvaialableException
                   consumeMessage(msg.getPayload());
                   return null;
               }
       );
   }
   catch (DBHostNotAvaialableException ex) {
     // once retries as per retrytemplate are  exhausted do a seek

       consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topicName, partition), offset);

   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
     // if some other exception just log and put in dlq based on enableDlq property
       logger.warn("some other business exception hence putting in dlq ");
       throw ex;
   }

   if (ack != null) {
       ack.acknowledge();
   }
   ```

   }

**Problem with this approach** - since I am doing consumer.seek() while there might be pending records from last poll those might be processed and committed if DB comes up during that period(hence out of order). Is there a way to clear those records while a seek is performed?

PS - we are currently in 2.0.3.RELEASE version of spring boot and Finchley.RELEASE or spring cloud dependencies (hence cannot use features like negative acknowledgement either and upgrade is not possible at this moment).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Stream does not use a container factory. I already explained that to you in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958078/how-to-set-concurrency-or-other-configurations-for-concurrentkafkalistenercont/60958873#60958873).

Version 2.1 introduced the `ListenerContainerCustomizer` and if you add a bean of that type it will be called after the container is created.

Spring Boot 2.0 went end-of-life over a year ago and is no longer supported.

The answer I referred you shows how you can use reflection to add an error handler.

Doing the seek in the listener will only work if you have `max.poll.records=1`.